# Relationship between Laplace Method and Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to learn about the Laplace Approximation of Integrals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). Supposedly, this is closely related to "Gaussian Functions".

Here is my current understanding - note that the Laplace Approximation is supposedly only valid for integrating functions of the form $\int e^{Mf(x)} \, dx$ (I don't know why this is):

Suppose we want to compute the integral $\int e^{Mf(x)} \, dx$. As I understand, the Laplace approximation involves the following steps:

1. **Find the mode**: The mode of $f(x)$, denoted $x^*$, is the value of $x$ that maximizes $f(x)$. I think we can use some numerical optimization methods like root finding/hill climbing to accomplish this.
2. **Second-order Taylor expansion**: While I don't understand why the Taylor Expansion is necessary for the Laplace Approximation, I think we need to evaluate the second-order Taylor expansion of $\log(f(x))$ around $x^*$:

$$
\log(f(x)) \approx \log(f(x^*)) + \frac{1}{2} f''(x^*) (x-x^*)^2
$$

Why can't we simply evaluate $f(x)$ at it's model $x^*$? Isn't the original function more accurate than its Taylor Expansion? Therefore, would it not make more sense to use the original function instead of its Taylor Expansion?

3. **Compute the integral**: The integral is then approximated by the Laplace Approximation:

$$
\int_a^b e^{M f(x)}\, dx\approx e^{M f(x^*)}\int_a^b e^{-\frac{1}{2} M|f''(x^*)| (x-x^*)^2} \, dx
$$

I have the following question:

- Why is the Taylor Expansion used in the Laplace Approximation? Why not just use the original function?
- And what is the relationship of the Laplace Approximation to the Gaussian Distribution? I don't directly see the Gaussian Distribution directly appear in any of this? know that any function of the type $e^{-x^2}$ is often called a Gaussian Function (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) .

I have heard that the Laplace Approximation is often related to the Gaussian Distribution somehow - but this is not clear to me. Is this integral the equivalent to a Normal/Gaussian Probability Density Function? For example, perhaps the result of the Laplace Approximation is a Normal Distribution with parameters:

$$N \sim (x*, \frac{1}{M|f''(x^*)|})$$
$$M|f''(x^*)| = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

Is this interpretation correct?

Thanks!

- Note: A very good video on Laplace Approximations that helped me : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvOuBTMIz3Y

Comment: For an example of this method being used in practice, you might find this post instructive: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288017/how-might-one-make-this-gaussian-integral-derivation-of-stirlings-approximation

Comment: @ Alex: thank you so much for your answer! Regarding 3) ...at the end I wrote an normal distribution centered around x* and variance M f''(x*). Is this correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that is roughly the correct interpretation, in the sense that $e^{-\frac{M}{2}|f''(x_*)|(x-x_*)^2}$ is the density of a Gaussian distribution (maybe not $L^1$ normalized) with mean $x_*$ and variance about $\frac{1}{M|f''(x_*)|}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form of exponential is just an easy form to deal with. In theory, if you have a fast decaying function, you can write in that exponential form easily.

1. If you are computing an integral like
   $$\int e^{-\lambda f(x)} g(x) dx $$
   where $f$ does not have a stationary point, i.e., $f'\neq 0$, then you can do integration by parts,
   $$\int e^{-\lambda f(x)} g(x) dx = \int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda f(x)}}{-\lambda f'}g(x)\right) dx - \int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{g(x) }{-\lambda f'(x)}\right) e^{-\lambda f(x)}dx$$
   The first part becomes zero if $g$ is compactly supported, otherwise the order of $1/\lambda$, and the second integral is a similar form as the original integral. In this case, you do not have to apply the Taylor expansion, your leading term has the order of $1/\lambda$.
2. If your $f$ has a stationary point, then the above way cannot work.  Assuming $\lambda$ is large, then your answer's leading order is the most important. That is why a Taylor expansion at the stationary point is needed, higher order expansion will not matter.
3. The relation with Gaussian is the integral in your step 3 is a so-called Gaussian integral. It computes the integral of a product between Gaussian density function and another function.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Regarding 3)   ...at the end I wrote an normal distribution centered around x* and variance M f''(x*). Is this correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: yes.  it is right.

Comment: thank you so much! Can you please go over the Taylor Expansion part again? Why is the Taylor Expansion needed?

Comment: if your M is large and $f''\neq 0$ at the stationary point, then the quadratic term contributes the leading term. Other higher order expansion terms will not contribute to that. R. Wong has a book about this, https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719260